# SELECT by string prefix using an index

Tags: sql, arrays, select, indexing, prefix

You have a column `foo`, of some string type, with a index on that column. You want to `SELECT` from the table `WHERE` the `foo` column has the prefix `'pre'`. Obviously, the index should be able to help here.

Here is the most obvious way to search by prefix:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE foo LIKE 'pre%';
```

Unfortunately, this does not get optimized to use the index (in Oracle or Postgres, at least).

The following, however, *does* work:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE 'pre' <= foo AND foo < 'prf';
```

But are there better ways to accomplish this, or are there ways of making the above more elegant? In particular:

- I need a function from `'pre'` to `'prf'`, but this has to work for any underlying collation. Also, it's more complicated than above, because if searching for e.g. `'prz'` then the upper bound would have to be `'psa'`, and so on.
- Can I abstract this into a stored function/procedure and still hit the index? So I could write something like `... WHERE prefix('pre', foo);`?

Answers for all DBMSes appreciated.

Comment: What? Unfortunately, this 'this does get optimized to use the index'? Was so bad about it? Of course, a 'begins with' search uses an index, if possible. Thanks god it does. .... Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: lol, sorry, I accidentally the word "not"! edited

Comment: Oh and do you mean there is a "begins with" construct in SQL? I can't find anything about that.

Comment: Yes, there is `Where Foo like 'bar%'` will enable an index.

Comment: It's very strange that `LIKE 'pre%'` can't use an index in those DBMSes. It is sargable in SQL Server, at least.

Comment: @alzaimar, what DBMS are you using? On Postgres, running `create table tab (foo text not null); create index tab_ix_foo on tab(foo); explain select * from tab where foo like 'pre%';` tells me it's going to do a sequential scan.

Comment: I checked that on Oracle and MSSQL. If am not too debil, even SQLite followed my instinct. And it's so obvious.

Comment: @ErikE, interesting. I do have a further reason to not use `LIKE`: when using a stored procedure with the prefix as a parameter, the optimizer won't be able to see that it's always a prefix search. (Presumably SQL Server only performs that optimization when given a string literal.)

Comment: @alzaimar, ooh, interesting. I've found that Postgres *does* optimize it, but only for certain collations. If I create the column and index to use collation `"POSIX"`, it optimizes. If i use `"en_US"`, it doesn't.

This worries me because I don't think the prefix-search problem should be affected by collation.

Comment: @eegg That's not entirely true. There is "parameter sniffing".

Answer (score 0):

The database is quite important here.  It so happens that SQL Server does this optimization for `like`.

One way is to do something like this:

```
where foo >= 'pre' and foo <= 'pre+'~'
```

'~' has the largest 7-bit ASCII value of a printable character, so it is basically bigger than anything else.  This however, may be a problem if you are using wide characters or a non-standard character set.

You cannot abstract this into a function, because use of a function generally precludes the use of indexes.  If you are always looking at the first three characters, then in Oracle you can create an index on those three characters (something called a "function-based index").

Comment: I don't think `foo <= 'pre~'` works, because it cuts out values like `'pre~fix'`. If using a `<=` comparison, the value would have to be `pre~~~~~~~~~...` carrying on forever.

Use of functions: I think you're right. Perhaps macros in SQL would be a nice thing, but that's pie-in-the-sky.

Answer (score -3):

How about

```
select * from tab where foo between 'pre' and 'prf' and foo != 'prf'
```

this enables the index same way. The RDBMS must be pretty dumb **not** to use an index for that.

Comment: You use inclusive end range, then have to specify another condition to make the end exclusive? Why not `foo >= 'pre' AND foo < 'prf'`?

Comment: Nice question. I haven't tried it, but from my guts it seems as if `between` is better. Hmm... Am I too much in belief where I should be more into proof?

Comment: Is `x BETWEEN l AND h` not just sugar for `l <= x AND x <= h`?

Comment: There's no way that `BETWEEN` can be better. As @eegg said, all it is is syntactic sugar expanded to two <= expressions, just like `IN` expands to `OR` expressions. You wouldn't say `'pre' <= foo AND ' foo <= 'pre' AND foo <> 'pre'`, would you? So it's "wrong" to do it with `BETWEEN`. Perhaps in the future more testing/proof is better than "instinct". :)