# Join table on substring-ed values

Tags: sql, sql-server

So basically, I have two table, X and Y. I want to join them with the substring-ed value but I'm unsure of how I can do so.

Sample code of X:

```
select distinct
    trim(ws.WS_name) as [WS Name],
    substring(trim(e.equip_id),1,8) as [Equid ID], 
into #eqm_hist
from eqmhist
```

Sample table of X:

| WS name | Equid ID |
| --- | --- |
| WS 21 | KTRGAF7L |
| WS 21 | KTRGAF7L |

Sample code of Y:

```
select distinct
    [Batch ID],
    [Qty],
    rtrim(flh.tracking_interface_id) as [Tool],
    [WS Name],
into #main 
from flh
```

Sample table of Y:

| Batch ID | Qty | Tool |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 100 | KTRGAF7L00 |
| 23456 | 100 | KTRGAF7L00 |

**Do note that [Tool] and [Equid ID] is the same**

How can I join them together using the substring-ed values to achieve the table like below?
Do I also have to remove the last two digit for [Tool] in table Y to do so?

| Batch ID | Qty | Tool | WS Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 100 | KTRGAF7L00 | WS 21 |
| 23456 | 100 | KTRGAF7L00 | WS 21 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592702/select-by-string-prefix-using-an-index), it appears that SQL Server will optimize a `LIKE 'prefix%'` condition to use an index.

So if you have an index on Y(Tool), you should be able to efficiently run the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM X
JOIN Y ON Y.Tool LIKE X.[Equid ID] + '%'
```

Follow-up note: If [Equid ID] values may have variable length, but the tool values will always have exactly two extra characters, you should change join condition to `ON Y.Tool LIKE X.[Equid ID] + '__'`. Underscores are single-character wildcards. This will handle vases where you have [Equid ID] values "Thing" and "ThingA" with Tool values "Thing01", "Thing02", "ThingA01", and "ThingA02".